# Convert local timestamp to RFC 3339 format in R

Tags: r, datetime

I pull the current datetime using `Sys.time()` and I get `"2018-05-12 11:52:21 EDT"`. How do I convert this to an RFC 3339 formatted string taking into account the local time zone is not UTC?

Note: The RFC 3339 format of this date is: `2018-05-12T15:52:21Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest thing I could come up with:

`format(lubridate::as_datetime(Sys.time()), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`

The pseudocode:

1. Use `as_datetime()` function from **lubridate** package, which by default, converts the timestamp into a POSIXct datetime representation using UTC as the timezone
2. Format that time using `format()`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that if you want an offset with the colon you can use the following:

```
.dt <- format(lubridate::now(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
paste0(stringr::str_sub(.dt, 1, -3),":", stringr::str_sub(.dt, -2, nchar(.dt)))
```

Comment: The `stamp()` function from lubridate can also handle the formatting of timezone offsets. It does this similarly to string substitution as done above. 
```lubridate::stamp("2020-01-01T00:00:00-04:00", quiet=TRUE)(lubridate::now())```
**LINK**: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/blob/master/R/stamp.r)